# Modify properties for individual controls in the details section of a form in continuous forms view

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a default view set to continuous forms. I want to set the enabled property of a command button control to disabled for records that have a null value in a specific column.

Comment: You can extend Dorians answer by using the enabled proptery of the button in the Details_Paint, but you have to  make sure the button has not the focus. But depending on the number of records, that may slow down the form. As alternative use Harasseds answer, combined with a textbox under the button that gets conditionally formated (e.g. red if disabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can't. What you need to do is start the button routine with an IF statement that says if the required control is null then exit sub. That way the button won't do anything if the field has a null value

Comment: thanks. that's what i'm doing now, but wanted to make it more apparent to the user that it's not supposed to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the caption in the `Detail_Paint` event for the form:

```
cb_SetSpecies.Caption = [Species_Name]
```

This allows a different value to be set for each record.